# How to store previous selected item from `DropDownList`

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `DropDownList`, using which I have to store some values from the `CheckBoxList` in the database.

Before I select another index from the `DropDownList`, the values in the `CheckBoxList` has to be stored, prompting the user with an alert "Save before proceeding".

I am able to display the above mention alert message. But the problem is once i change the index it `DropDownList`, the previous selected index is lost.

Can someone kindly help me getting the previous selected value and select the same dynamically in `DropDownList`. Because the value is need to store in database.

The code for displaying alert message is:

```
protected void LOC_LIST2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckBoxList2.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            Label7.Visible = true;
            Label7.Text = "*Save List Before Proceeding";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

With the use of Global variables.

Using the code below. `PreviousIndex` will hold the previous, and `CurrentIndex` will hold current.

```
int PreviousIndex = -1;
int CurrentIndex = -1;

protected void LOC_LIST2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PreviousIndex = CurrentIndex;
    CurrentIndex = myDropdownList.Position; // Or whatever the get position is.
    if (CheckBoxList2.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        Label7.Visible = true;
        Label7.Text = "*Save List Before Proceeding";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the selected value first time the page load as

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

    if (!IsPostBack) // Because When postback occurs the selected valued changed.
    {
        ViewState["PreviousValue"] = ddl.SelectedValue;
    }
 }
```

and in your selected index change event update your previous value by the new value as

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["NewValue"] = ddl.SelectedValue;

    // Do your work with PreviousValue and then update it with NewValue so next you can acces your previousValue using ViewState["PreviousValue"]

    ViewState["PreviousValue"] = ViewState["NewValue"];   
}
```

or If you want to access selected value on different pages then save it in Session.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this code - bu using session caching

```
public string YourOldValue
{
  get
  {
     if(Session["key"] != null) 
        return (string) Session["key"];
  }
  set
  {
     Session["key"] = value;
  }   

 }

 //Set value
 YourOldValue = yourControl.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void LOC_LIST2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["SavedItem"] =  LOC_LIST2.SelectedItem;
            if (CheckBoxList2.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                Label7.Visible = true;
                Label7.Text = "*Save List Before Proceeding";
            }
        }

after you access on value or text
SelectedItem item = Session["SavedItem"] as SelectedItem;
if(item !=null)
{
string something= item.Value;
string otherthing =item.Text;
}
```

Comment: When SelectedIndexChanged is called SelectedItem is changed.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what finally worked for me. A combination of the answers above.

You have to track both previous and current selected index/value in the OnLoad handler of the page/control.

```
private int PreviousSelectedIndex
{
    get { return (Page.ViewSate["prevIdx"] == null) ? -1 : (int)ViewSate["prevIdx"]; }
    set { Page.ViewSate["prevIdx"] = value; }
}

private int CurrentSelectedIndex
{
    get { return (Page.ViewSate["currIdx"] == null) ? -1 : (int)ViewSate["currIdx"]; }
    set { Page.ViewSate["currIdx"] = value; }
}

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        PreviousDropDownValue = ddlYourDropDownList.SelectedValue;
        CurrentDropDownValue = ddlYourDropDownList.SelectedValue;
    }
    else if (Page.IsPostBack && CurrentDropDownValue != ddlYourDropDownList.SelectedValue)
    {
        PreviousDropDownValue = CurrentDropDownValue;
        CurrentDropDownValue = ddlYourDropDownList.SelectedValue;
    }
}
```

After that you can compare the previous and current values with each other.